Firefox browser integration with KeepassXC not working - Apparmor issue?
Multiple versions of firefox from the PPA (not snap - I've removed all snaps and snapd) across multiple versions of Ubuntu in the past two years have failed to produce a working browser integration of keepassxc. The browser extension shows this initial error:
 Cannot connect to KeePassXC. Check that browser integration is enabled in KeePassXC settings. 

Attempting to click the reload button gives me this error message:
 Key exchange was not successful.

The database is running and unlocked, and the settings have the browser integration enabled.
I've attempted to follow the instructions from the troubleshooting guide on Github (Link for reference). However, when running aa-enforce, I get the below error:
ERROR: Conflicting profiles for firefox defined in two files:
- /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
- /etc/apparmor.d/firefox

The guide has no information on what to do about this, and searching for the exact phrase of the first line in Google returns zero results. I also tried aa-disable and received the same error.
Where to from here? I'm open to software alternatives that work on Linux and Android as well, if there's no fix.
Currently using Firefox 132.0.2 and Ubuntu 24.10

Which version of Ubuntu are you using? I use Firefox (both snap and ppa) and keepassxc. I have not seen this.

@user68186 - 24.10 with Firefox 132

Have you tried to run sudo journalctl -t audit | grep 'apparmor="DENIED"' | grep "$(which keepassxc-proxy)"? What is the output?
